# Javascript add numbers of same number in variable

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need javasctript function that writes number of 1 together witch depends on value counter.
So if is counter 6 write number 1 six time together.

Here is example output what i need:

```
 var counter = 6;

 var output = "111111";
```

I search forum here...but i have not found any solution how to make this.Any help is welcomed.

Comment: you are going to need a `for` loop

Comment: Seems like you didn't even try ... shame ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a one-liner

```
var output = Array(counter + 1).join("1");   //"111" for counter = 3
```

Cheers

Comment: thank You...this is the shortes code as possible...so here is complete code that contains Your solution. If someoneneeds it here is it. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that does what you want:

```
function repeat(letter, count) {
  var answer = '';

  while(count--) {
    answer += letter;
  }

  return answer;
}

// usage:
var onesixtimes = repeat('1', 6); // '111111'
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:***

Completely forgot that ES6 will also have a `String.prototype.repeat` method:

```
var s = "1".repeat(6);
```

This is available right now in Firefox, but a patch is needed for older browsers.

---

***Original answer:***

ECMAScript 6 will have a `Array.prototype.fill` method.

```
var s = Array(6).fill("1").join("");
```

You can use it now with a compatibility patch.

Something like this should be close, though perhaps not entirely compatible:

```
if (!Array.prototype.fill) {
    Array.prototype.fill = function(val, start, end) {
        start = parseInt(start)
        start = isNaN(start) ? 0 :
                start < 0    ? Math.max(this.length + start, 0) :
                               Math.min(this.length, start)

        end = parseInt(end)
        end = isNaN(end) ? this.length :
              end < 0    ? Math.max(this.length + end, 0) :
                           Math.min(this.length, end)

        while (start < end)
            this[start++] = val

        return this
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to join afterwarsd to turn it into the string the OP expects.

Comment: @Tibos: Thanks, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzC5y/) that shows it working

```
function writeNum(counter, integer){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        arr.push(integer);
    }
    return arr.join("");
}
```